# NSCoding UIImage to disk takes up huge amount of disk space and writes slowly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding

I am serializing UIImages to disk using NSKeyedArchiver.

UIImage conforms to NSCoding so serializes+deserializes properly but the resulting file is quite large causing performance issues.

I tested this by loading images from the ALAssetsLibrary taken on a standard iPhone5 camera to a UIImage and then serializing images to disk

```
UIImage *testImage = [asset defaultRepresentation]....
[NSKeyedArchiver archive:testImage ....]
```

The files were ~15MB and took over 1 second to write/load.

Then I tried serializing the UIImage by converting to NSData:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, 0....1); // tried most compression all the way to least compression
[NSKeyedArchiver archive:imageData....]
```

The resulting files were magnitude smaller (so faster to read and write)

What is the suggested way to save images? are the underlying images from the ALAssetsLibrary also taking 15MB on disk to store the images?

Should I be using PNG representation?

Comment: What was the size of the testImage object?

Comment: How can I test the size of an ALAssetsLibrary Image?

Comment: You don't need an archiver in your last example - save and read the data object directly using convenience methods of NSData.

Comment: Maybe something like NSLog(@"SIZE %zd", malloc_size(testImage)); or NSLog(@"SIZE %lu", sizeof(testImage)); or using Instruments. You'll figure that out...

Comment: Yes, @DavidH is right.

Comment: I wanted to know why the big difference in size. The archiving part is clear.

Comment: @AvnerBarr have you found the cause? Not sure why a 3000 x 2000 image only takes 1.5MB in iPhone Photo Library, but takes 15MB if I store in CoreData

Comment: Not sure - I guess the coding of it includes additional information (Perhaps thumbnails? ) or maybe a bad algorithm (Not PNG) - If you have no choice , try using  ```UIImagePNGRepresentation(<#UIImage *image#>)```